# Robots.txt to allow a few specific crawlers and deny all others

Tags: yahoo, robots.txt, googlebot, msn

I have been getting a lot of CPU spikes recently on my server and somehow I believe it's not the real traffic or some part of it isn't real. So I want to only allow Google bots, MSN and Yahoo for now. Please guide me if the following robots.txt file is correct for my requirement.

```
User-agent: Googlebot
User-agent: Slurp
User-agent: msnbot 
User-agent: Mediapartners-Google*
User-agent: Googlebot-Image 
User-agent: Yahoo-MMCrawler
Disallow: 

User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your robots.txt seems to be valid.

- It is [allowed to have several `User-agent` lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20307057/1591669) in a record.
- `Disallow:` allows crawling everything.
- The record starting with `User-agent: *` only applies to bots not matched by the previous record.
- `Disallow: /` forbids crawling anything.

But note: Only nice bots follow the rules in robots.txt -- and it’s likely that nice bots don’t overdo common crawling frequencies. So either you need to work on your performance, or not-so-nice bots are to blame.

Comment: I disallow "dalvik" which use a lot of banwith but dalvik still crawl my site.

Answer (score -1):

That first `Disallow:` should probably be:

```
Allow: /
```

if you want to, in fact, allow all those user agents to index your site.

Comment: Actually, the standard allows for a blank `Disallow:`. See the examples at http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html. Also the original specification at http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html

Comment: `Allow` isn’t even part of the original robots.txt specification (but many parsers, including Google’s, support it).