# How to allow multiple robot in robot.txt

Tags: bots, robots.txt

```
User-Agent:*
Disallow:/

User-Agent: Googlebot
User-Agent: Googlebot-Mobile
User-Agent: Googlebot-Image
User-Agent: Bingbot
Allow:/
```

Does this allow all 4 bots or just allow Bingbot and disallow everything?

**Edit**
My Answer could be useful for people who forget/don't know how to test robot.txt

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to list multiple user-agents in one line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20294485/is-it-possible-to-list-multiple-user-agents-in-one-line)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the best solution for this,
check your Search Console page and test their bots in there.

For example:

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/robots-testing-tool

https://webmaster.yandex.com/robots.xml

http://tools.seobook.com/robots-txt/analyzer/